# Interesting way of determining that every integer is divisible by a prime?

Tags: number-theory, alternative-proof

Is is possible to deduce that every integer is divisible by a prime from the fact that the set of integers *not* divisible by a prime has natural density zero?

Preferably, I would not be looking for, "Yes, by a classic proof.", but rather some number-theoretic trickery with the above fact or some deductions from really elementary ideas about numbers.

Comment: $$\qquad 1 \qquad$$

Comment: This type of question usually leads to much back-and-forth as it is not sufficiently clear -cut what "deduce from" will mean.

Comment: @quid This is a *very weak* argument to support such a rapid closure.  Please be more careful wielding such power. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @BillDubuque quick closures are better for questions that might be "saved". It prevents unsuitable answers like the one already given to pile up before the question is clarified. (Surely OP was aware for the content of that answer.)

Comment: @quid The only "saving" needed here is from abuse of moderator powers. There is nothing wrong with the question (except that you don't like it for some reason that is far from clear).

Comment: @BillDubuque please avoid meta-discussion on main.

Answer (score 2):

No, because a set with natural density zero can still have members.  For example the powers of $2$ have natural density $0$, but we cannot use that to prove that there are no numbers that are powers of $2$.